# How to separate text by words using regex?

Tags: c#

I have .srt file which has some text structure.
Example:

```
1
00:00:01,514 --> 00:00:04,185
I'm investigating
Saturday night's shootings.

2
00:00:04,219 --> 00:00:05,754
What's to investigate?
Innocent people
```

I expect to get splitted words like "I'm", "investigating", "Saturday" etc.

I've created pattern

```
@"[a-zA-Z']"
```

which separate my text almost correct.
But .srt files also contain some useless tag-structures like this

```
<i>
```

which I want to remove.

How can I build my pattern which will separate text by words and remove all text between '<' and '>' (include braces)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well its very hard to do this in regexp(well for me at least) in one way, but you could do this in two steps.

First you remove the html character from the string then extract the words after that.

Have a look below.

```
var text = "00:00:01,514 --> 00:00:04,185 I'm investigating Saturday night's shootings.<i>"

// remove all html char
var noHtml = Regex.Replace(text, @"(<[^>]*>).*", "");

// and now you could get only the words by using @"[a-zA-Z']" on noHtml. You should get "I'm investigating Saturday night's shootings."
```

Answer (score 1):

You can negative look arounds to assert that there is no sequence of not `<`s ended by a `>` following and no sequence of a `<` followed by a sequence of not `>`s preceding.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string input = @"
<garbage>
Hello world, <rubbish>it's a wonderful day.



<trash>
";
        foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input, @"(?<!<[^>]*)[a-zA-Z']+(?![^<]*>)"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Hello
world
it's
a
wonderful
day
```

[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/meHjf8)